# how to report missing files in a list, usable in python script?

Tags: scripting, python

Is there any simple way to get **all missing `.blend` libraries**, in a python `list`, `set`, `tuple` or `dictionary`?

The operator `bpy.ops.file.report_missing_files()` only prints this list in the console. If I put it in a variable, the only thing I have is a set: `{'FINISHED'}` !! To illustrate:

```
missing_libs = bpy.ops.file.report_missing_files()
# missing libraries are printed in the console at this point, one line a file
print(missing_libs)
# prints {'FINISHED'} in the console
```

Ideally, I want to be able to do, for example:

```
nb_missing_libs = len(missing_libs) # get the number of missing libraries
for mlib in missing_libs:
    if ".blend" in mlib:
        # Do something with mlib
```

Is there a fast and easy way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try a variation of the following code:

```
import bpy
import os

def list_missing_blend_libs():
    return [bpy.path.abspath(lib.filepath) for lib in bpy.data.libraries
            if not os.path.exists(bpy.path.abspath(lib.filepath))]
```

Using [`bpy.path.abspath`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_2/bpy.path.html#bpy.path.abspath), it only lists absolute path of missing libraries in [`bpy.data.libraries`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_2/bpy.types.BlendData.html#bpy.types.BlendData.libraries).